# handiling CROS in ionic

Tags: rest, ionic-framework

i was trying to use an remote api in my ionic app..but its showing following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54276/api/products?key1=value1&key2=value2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

am running on `chrome` using `ionic serve`...
i read some articles on ionic blog regarding CROS  but i didn't get it well.can any one help me to fix it here is my`controller` code

```
$scope.getData = function() {
        $http.get("http://localhost:54276/api/products", { params: { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } })
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.username = data.username;
                $scope.password = data.password;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                alert("Sorry");
            });
    }
```

Comment: do you have this in your config.xml .. <access origin="*"/> ??

Comment: no. can you please tell where to add..?

Comment: above <preference> tag

Comment: yes <access origin="*"/> is there alredy

Comment: ok then you should set header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"  for your http method

Comment: CORS only appears when testing on a browser with ionic serve. CORS will not happen on a device. That being said, why not just use the chrome or mozilla CORS plugin? Like, this 1 https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every one..just made it by adding

```
 "proxies": [{
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "//your url"
}]
```

to `ionic.config`

Answer (score 0):

Send header with you http request

```
var request = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'http://localhost:54276/api/products',
 headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
 },
 params: { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
}

$http(request).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Hopes this help you . thanks

Comment: then I think , It's backend issue